# Finding the value of a complex number raised to a large exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> Find the value of
>   $$\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}i)^{53}}{2^{53}}$$

The answer I get to is $-1 + 0i$, which is incorrect.

I start with putting $1-\sqrt{3}i$ into polar form.

I know that given a complex number in form $x + iy$ we have the following:
$$
x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta
$$
And I know that $r=\left|x+iy\right|$.
$$
r=\sqrt{1^2+(-\sqrt3)^2}=\sqrt{4}=2
$$
This all yields,
\begin{align*}
1&=2\cos\theta\\
\frac{1}{2}&=\cos\theta\\
\theta&=\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}\quad\text{(for }\cos\theta\text{)}\\
\\\
-\sqrt3&=2\sin\theta\\
\frac{-\sqrt3}{2}&=\sin\theta\\
\theta&=\frac{-\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}\quad\text{(for }\sin\theta\text{)}
\end{align*}
Which gives me a polar form as follows.
$$
1-\sqrt{3}i=2\left(\cos{\frac{5\pi}{3}}+\sin{\frac{5\pi}{3}}\right)
$$

De Moivre's Formula tells me that
$$
(r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^n=r^n(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)
$$

So taking the original fraction given,
\begin{align*}
&\quad\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}i)^{53}}{2^{53}}\\
&= \frac{2^{53}\left(\cos\frac{53\times5\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{53\times5\pi}{3}\right)}{2^{53}}\\
&= \cos(\frac{159\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{159\pi}{3})\\
&= \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)\quad\text{Since these repeat every }2\pi\\
&= -1 + 0i
\end{align*}

I’ve clearly made a faulty assumption somewhere here, but I am not sure where.

Edit: Yup, simple arithmetic error described in comments and accepted answer. Final answer is $\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

Comment: 53*5=265, isn't it?

Comment: Well, $53\times5=265$.

Comment: Ah, yup, that was the whole issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$53\cdot\frac{5\pi}3=\frac{265\pi}{3}=44\cdot2\pi+\frac\pi3$$

so $\cos\left(53\cdot\frac{5\pi}3\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)$ and $\sin\left(53\cdot\frac{5\pi}3\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Without too much effort or indeed any trig, all you need to really do is notice that

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^{53}&=\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^{51}\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^2\\&=\left(\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^3\right)^{17}\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)\\&=\left(-1\right)^{17}\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)\\&=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\end{align}$$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks man